# MATLAB - Plot means on boxplot for different categories of data

Tags: matlab

I have a boxplot with six different categories plotted. These categories have been read in from different columns of an Excel spreadsheet. I would like to display the mean of each category on its associated box. After using the boxplot function, I have:

```
hold on
plot(mean(data1), 'r+')
```

This plots the mean of the first category of data correctly. However, if I continue on with the code and do this:

```
hold on
plot(mean(data1), 'r+')
hold on
plot(mean(data2), 'r+')
```

it will plot the mean of data2 at the x-axis location of data1 instead of at the x-axis location of data2. Is there a way I can tell the program to plot each category's mean at specific x-axis locations that correspond to each category?

Here is the remainder of my code:

```
% create boxplots for altitudinal and areal extent for all categories

% read in altitudinal extent for all categories
% nontor
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'nontornadic','C5:C48');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
NonAltExt = str2double(raw);

% tornadic
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'tornadic','C5:C78');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
TorsAltExt = str2double(raw);

% all tornadoes
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'tornadic','F5:F78');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
all_torsAltExt = str2double(raw);

% no tornadoes
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'tornadic','O5:O78');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
notorAltExt = str2double(raw);

% weak tornadoes
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'tornadic','I5:I78');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
weakAltExt = str2double(raw);

% significant tornadoes
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('SupercellEnvironmentalVariables.xlsx',...
'tornadic','L5:L78');
% find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
% convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = 
cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
sigAltExt = str2double(raw);


AltExt = [NonAltExt;TorsAltExt;all_torsAltExt;notorAltExt;...
weakAltExt;sigAltExt];
g = [ones(size(NonAltExt)); 2*ones(size(TorsAltExt)); 
3*ones(size(all_torsAltExt));...
4*ones(size(notorAltExt)); 5*ones(size(weakAltExt)); 
6*ones(size(sigAltExt))];

Figure1 = figure;
bh = boxplot(AltExt,g,'symbol','k*');
% patch fill each box to get a color fill with some transparency
h = findobj(gca,'Tag','Box');
for j=1:length(h)
    patch(get(h(j),'XData'),get(h(j),'YData'),'y','FaceAlpha',.5,'FaceColor',[1 1 1],...
     'EdgeColor',[0 0 0]);
end
hold on
plot(mean(NonAltExt),'r+')
title('Mean Z_D_R Col. Max. Altitude > 0\circC (km) for All Categories',...
'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Mean Z_D_R Col. Max. Altitude > 0\circC 
(km)','FontSize',10,'FontWeight','bold')
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0])
set(gca,'xticklabel',[{'Nontornadic','Tornadic','All Tornado Sam. Vols.',...
'No Tornado Sam. Vols.','Weak Tornado Sam. Vols.',...
'Significant Tornado Sam. Vols.'}],'XTickLabelRotation',45)
set(bh(:,:),'linewidth',1.5);
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';

% set color and increase thickness of median lines
median_lines = findobj(gca, 'type', 'line', 'Tag', 'Median');
set(median_lines, 'LineWidth',2.5, 'Color','r');
ax.Children = ax.Children([end 1:end-1]);   % allows median lines to be 
plotted on top of box fill
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hold on
plot(1,mean(data1), 'r+')
plot(2,mean(data2), 'r+')
```

Here I'm using the `plot(x,y)` syntax. If you leave X out, as you did, MATLAB assumes 1.

Also, you only need to give `hold on` once.

Comment: I was able to find another way to do it after taking a break from looking at it and coming back to it, but I tried your solution as well and both work the same way. What you said makes sense in that I'm leaving out the 'x' part and only plotting 'y'. Thank you so much!