# display mean instead of median in boxplot matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, boxplot

I have the example code below:

```
A = [16 20 15 17 22 19 17]';
 B = [22 15 16 16 16 18]';
 C = [23 9 15 18 13 27 17 14 16 15 21 19 17]';

 group = [ ones(size(A));
          2 * ones(size(B));
          3;
          4 * ones(size(C))
           ];

       figure();
           boxplot([A; B; NaN; C],group);
             set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'A','B','','C'});
```

what can I add to the code to show the mean of each vector in the box plot instead of the median (which is a Matlab default), I know how to do it for one vector but if we have multiple boxplots, I need some help how to do it.

any suggestion, please?

Comment: This must be some school exercise... We had the exact same question earlier today. A classmate or pure coincidence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB - Plot means on boxplot for different categories of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138577/matlab-plot-means-on-boxplot-for-different-categories-of-data)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think coincidence. I am not part of any class. self study!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the median line and then plotting the relevant means
:

```
A = [16 20 15 17 22 19 17]';
B = [22 15 16 16 16 18]';
C = [23 9 15 18 13 27 17 14 16 15 21 19 17]';
% Calculate means
meanOfA = mean(A);
meanOfB = mean(B);
meanOfC = mean(C);
group = [ ones(size(A));
      2 * ones(size(B));
      3;
      4 * ones(size(C))
       ];

figure;
boxplot([A; B; NaN; C],group);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'A','B','','C'});
% Find handle for median line and set visibility off
h = findobj(gca,'Tag','Median');
set(h,'Visible','off');
%plot means as black asterisks.
hold on
plot(1,meanOfA, 'k*')
plot(2,meanOfB, 'k*')
plot(4,meanOfC, 'k*')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to add the line instead of star on the mean place? I tried plot(1,meanOfA, 'k-') did not work.